# Distribution nonlinear sum and product of indepent variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given two random variables x,y with associated PDFs $f_X$, and $f_Y$ what is the PDF of $z(x,y) = x + y + xy$ and is there a general solution for a function of n terms such that $z(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ =  linear and interaction terms only?

My first attempt was to decompose the problem and consider the PDF of $(x+y)$ then the PDF of $(xy)$ then consider the sum of those two (effecivly looking at the problem as $(x+y)$ + $(xy)$  but in that case I end up considering the $x$ in the $(x+y)$ term as independent from the $x$ in the $xy$ term (same with the $y's$) which of course isn't true.

Edit: should have mentioned I am assuming $x$ and $y$ are independent, or in the general case $x_i$ and $x_j$ for $i \neq j$

Comment: Consider the CDF of $Z = X + Y + XY$, then use law of total probability conditioning on either $X$ or $Y$. Finally do the differentiation and the integration to obtain the pdf.

Comment: This problem cannot be solved since we need to know the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. Just knowing the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ is not enough.  It would be a different story if $X$ and $Y$ were independent.